# How to set handlers context path programmatically with wild cards in jetty?

Tags: java, jetty

Usually in jetty you specify the context path in xml

```
<bean id="myHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.MyHandler">
    <property name="handler" ref="myHandler" />
    <property name="contextPath" value="/myHandler" />
</bean>
```

Is there a way to set a handler with wild path contextpath programmatically without xml?

Answer (score 2):

`contextPath` is the parent path for all content under that context.

Jetty will only submit your request to that Handler if the `contextPath` matches.
This is essentially a read-only value that can only be set before startup of that Handler's LifeCycle.

So if you used say `/api` then that's essentially the same as `/api/*` and `/api/`

You can then use the standard `HttpServletRequest` details to get access to what URI was actually submitted to you.

You might want to just use `ServletContextHandler` and normal Servlets if you have a need to slice/dice the URI in more complex ways.

You can even take advantage of the [`PathMappings`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/a3f1592c50c3af7001a5ab3c773768660eb8d07a/jetty-http/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/pathmap/PathMappingsTest.java) found in the `ServletContextHandler` to map your Servlet's in creative ways (prefix, exact, suffix, glob, regex, uri-template, etc).